# Efficiently finding all numbers in two sets defined by each other

Tags: diophantine-equations, recursion, programming

In my recreational endeavours of metamethematics, I've come across two sets $\mathbb{A}$ and $\mathbb{B}$ whose elements are defined recursively by eachother.

Initially, we are given a countable infinite set of "seeds" in $\mathbb{A}$.

$$\forall (n,k)\in\mathbb{N}_0^2\Big[g(n)+3^{n+1}\phi(k,k)\in\mathbb{A}\Big]$$

where $g(n)=\frac{1}{2}(3^n(3n(n-1)+7)-3)$, and $\phi:\mathbb{N}_0^2\to\mathbb{N}_0$, is a bijection, defined by
$$\phi(m,n)=\begin{cases}m^2+2n & m\geq n\\ n^2+2m+1 & m < n \\ \end{cases}.$$

For example, $(n,k)=(0,0)\implies 2\in\mathbb{A}.$

Then, we are given a curious set of 5 rules which "generate" other integers in $\mathbb{A}$ and $\mathbb{B}$:

$$
\begin{align}
    &\forall a\in\mathbb{A}\Big[3a+1\in\mathbb{B}\Big]\\
    &\forall b\in\mathbb{B}\Big[3b+1\in\mathbb{A}\Big]\\
    &\forall (a,b,n)\in(\mathbb{A}\times\mathbb{B}\times\mathbb{N}_0)\Big[g(n)+3^{n+1}\phi(a,b)\in\mathbb{B}\Big]\\
    &\forall (a,n,k)\in(\mathbb{A}\times\mathbb{N}_0\times\mathbb{N}_0)\Big[g(n)+3^{n+1}\phi(k,a)\in\mathbb{A}\Big]\\
    &\forall (b,n,k)\in(\mathbb{B}\times\mathbb{N}_0\times\mathbb{N}_0)\Big[g(n)+3^{n+1}\phi(b,k)\in\mathbb{A}\Big]\\
\end{align}
$$

I wrote a few python scripts that, when given a number $M$, inefficently apply all these rules iteratively until no new numbers less than $M$ appear within either $\mathbb{A}$ or $\mathbb{B}$. However, my code takes on the order of an hour to calculate all the entries less than $M=2^{16}$. I would like to go to much larger orders of magnitudes, but the method I employ seems to take exponentially longer as I increase $M$.

> Hence, besides using a faster language than python, what theorems or methods can I use to efficiently calculate all elements in $\mathbb{A}$ and $\mathbb{B}$ less than a given $M$? Can this be done in polynomial time?

Although I am unfamiliar with the area, my intuition tells me that this may boil down to a set of diophantine equations.

If it's relevant, I should point out that $\mathbb{A}\cap\mathbb{B}=\emptyset\wedge\mathbb{A}\cup\mathbb{B}\subset\mathbb{N}_0$.

**Note:** I am at a bit of a loss for what tags this question relates to best, so please feel free add any you deem relevent.

Comment: What is $\mathbb N_0$?

Comment: @DonThousand your classic natural numbers (with zero).

Comment: You claim that $\Bbb{A}\cap\Bbb{B}=\varnothing$, but I think this is not true. The third rule shows that for any $(a,b,b)\in\Bbb{A}\times\Bbb{B}\times\Bbb{N}$ we have
$$g(b)+3^{b+1}\phi(b,a)\in\Bbb{B},$$
and the fourth rule shows that for $(a,b,b)\in\Bbb{A}\times\Bbb{N}\times\Bbb{N}$ we have
$$g(b)+3^{b+1}\phi(b,a)\in\Bbb{A}.$$
This shows that $\Bbb{A}\cap\Bbb{B}\neq\varnothing$. (Because of course $\Bbb{A}$ and $\Bbb{B}$ are nonempty.) Let me know if I have misunderstood something.

Comment: @Servaes. Ah, good catch! My mistake, had the variables the other way around ($\phi(b,a)$ should have been $\phi(a,b)$). Should be fixed now.